# Why after `setup.py develop` new submodules are not available?

Tags: python, setuptools

Why should I run again `setup.py develop` after adding new scripts/submodules etc. ?

For exemple I do that :

```
pyvenv venv
. venv/bin/activate
```

Now, create these files:

```
/
| setup.py
| testpkg
|  | __init__.py
|  | foo.py
|  |__
|__
```

(setup.py is a simple one, and foo.py contains one function)
then,

```
python setup.py develop
```

Now, if you start python, you can import `testpkg.foo`.

But now, add bar.py :

```
/
| setup.py
| testpkg
|  | __init__.py
|  | foo.py
|  | bar.py      <---
|  |__
|__
```

you can't import `testpkg.bar`

except if you run again

```
python setup.py develop
```

Why ? (why doesn't it work, and why having chosen this behavior if it's the expected one ?)

**NOTE (and edit)**

on my computer, after running `python setup.py develop`, I note that the link points to the build/lib/[...].egg-info

and in the egg info, I see that the sources point to this build/lib. the files in here are not links, so how is it supposed to work ??

Comment: uh... why -1 Oo ...I checked this question has not been asked before, and this is a real problem since editable mode is just not working on my computer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the flag use_2to3 is set. Then , as doc says :

> If you have enabled the use_2to3 flag, then of course the .egg-link
>   will not link directly to your source code when run under Python 3,
>   since that source code would be made for Python 2 and not work under
>   Python 3. Instead the setup.py develop will build Python 3 code under
>   the build directory, and link there. This means that after doing code
>   changes you will have to run setup.py build before these changes are
>   picked up by your Python 3 installation.

- https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html